# Qt: in an int variable i want to keep colour information

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing a tetris.
This is my implementation of the glass. I just want to draw what is inside it.
Int means a colour (int glass_array[10][22];).

Now I want to find out how to use those colours. For learning purposes I create two
cubes and want them to be of different colours. Say, red and green. But they both have turned out to be blue.

Could you help me?

**QtGlass.h**

```
class QtGlass : public QFrame {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event);
    QtGlass(QWidget *parent);
    bool key_pressed;
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event);
protected:
    void glassRedraw(QPainter &painter);
    int glass_array[10][22];
};
```

**QtGlass.cpp**

```
QtGlass::QtGlass(QWidget *parent): QFrame(parent) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 22; j++) {
            glass_array[i][j] = 0; //0 - Default color (grey);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 8; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 20; j < 22; j++) {
            glass_array[i][j] = QColor(Qt::green).value(); // green 
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 20; j < 22; j++) {
            glass_array[i][j] = QColor(Qt::red).value(); // red 
        }
    }    
}




void QtGlass::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
    QPainter painter(this);
    Figure Falcon;

    glassRedraw(painter);
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::red, 4));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 22; j++) {
            if (glass_array[i][j] > 0) {
                painter.fillRect(i* 31+ 1, j * 31 + 1, 29, 29,
                        QBrush(QColor(glass_array[i][j]), Qt::SolidPattern));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not `QColor glass_array[10][22];` ?

Comment: I guess he wants to preserve memory usage and I guess he is not doing it right. keeping them as QColor will save him from creating and destroying QColor object with each paint event :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use some of the C++ power that Qt put at your disposition:

If you declare `QVector< QVector<QColor> > glass_array;` you will get more safety: for instance, after this declaration

```
QVector< QVector<QColor> > glass_array(10, QVector<QColor>(22));
glass_array[9][21] = Qt::red;  // this is OK
// this causes 
// ASSERT failure in QVector<T>::operator[]: "index out of range", file ../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/include/QtCore/qvector.h, line 359
glass_array[9][22] = Qt::blue;
```

If you decide to go this way, that member declaration must be 'split': in class QtGlass declare

```
QVector< QVector<QColor> > glass_array;
```

then initialize in constructor:

```
QtGlass::QtGlass(QWidget *parent):
   QFrame(parent),
   glass_array(10, QVector<QColor>(22))
{...}
```

Comment: As suggested above, array of QColor type works perfectly. Could you clarify what there is in your method which is safier?

Comment: There is support for index check - at debug time, as I showed with the out-of-bounds access